# Cannot configure Grails 3.0.4 in GGTS, Grails installed using GVM

Tags: grails, ggts, gvm

I have installed GGTS 3.6.4 and also Groovy & Grails using GVM on my MAC OS.
In GGTS, Preferences - Configure Grails Installation - Add, I want to add the latest grails installed by GVM in /Users/user/.gvm/grails/current
I have also enabled the hidden folders in Mac.

Answer (score 1):

grails version 3.x.x doesn't contain build.properties file.

So, you should follow the following steps:

1. Create /grails-3.x.x/build.properties file.
2. Inside build.properties write the content version name as

> grails.version=3.1.1

3. Now, open GGTS .
4. Go to Window/Preferences.
5. Type grails in the 'type filter text'.
6. Select Grails.
7. Now click on Add button on the right panel to add grails version 3.x.x .
8. Select the grails version from the My computer.
9. You are ready to go.

Your GGTS will recognize it as now Grails installation.

Comment: It allows to install grails but you can't work any further

Answer (score 0):

According to the [GGTS website](https://grails.org/products/ggts), it only supports Grails 1.3/2.x (not the latest Grails 3.x). Pivotal discontinued support for GGTS earlier this year.

The best IDE alternative currently is [IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/groovy.html). Grails 3 is built on Gradle, so no special support for Grails is necessary as IDEA already has excellent support for Gradle projects.

Comment: @Tejaswee: You're welcome! If it works for you, consider accepting the answer or asking for more info. :)